# Rest API: What do first, distinguish REQUEST_METHOD or PATH_INFO?

Tags: php, rest, api, httprequest, pathinfo

I am working on a small `REST API`, written in `PHP`.
Is there a best practice, to decide what the script should do?
Do I first check if the request is `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` or do I check first the `PATH_INFO`.
Example first check `PATH_INFO`:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'))[0];
switch ($request) 
{
  case 'books':
    if ($method = 'GET') 
      {
        getbooks();
      } elseif ($method = 'POST')
      {
        postbooks();
      }
  break;
  default:
    include_once('error.php');
  break;
}
```

Example first check REQUEST_METHOD:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'))[0];
switch ($method) 
{
  case 'GET':
    if ($request = 'books') 
      {
        getbooks();
      } elseif ($request = 'user')
      {
        getuser();
      }
  break;
  default:
    include_once('error.php');
  break;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Also, the API`will be very limited. Mostly a path will have only one possible`REQUEST_METHOD`.

Comment: Read some blogs & tutorials http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/ and if you get stuck come back an ask more detailed. In php you can do everthing like you want, but here on SO we wont explain to everbody what the best practise are.

Comment: And only a REST API for one type read/write/.. `books` is not a real REST API. The API should do more than that.

Comment: I use `POST` and `GET` and have more than `books`. It was only a small example to explain my question! Thank you for the Link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple and understandable. Then I would prefer the following

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'))[0];

if($method == "GET" && $request == "books"){
    getBooks();
}elseif ($method == "POST" && $request == "books"){
    addBooks();
}elseif ($method == "PUT" && $request == "books"){
    updateBooks();
}elseif ($method == "DELETE" && $request == "books"){
    deleteBooks();
}
```